# Compiler error with text width, font, hyperref, footnote

Tags: compiling

I have a strange combination of font, typography, where compilation fails with

> Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 39.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={150mm,237mm},
 left=30mm,
 top=30mm,
 }

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
% get rid of the horrible coloured boxes around links
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lf]{venturis} %% lf option gives lining figures as default; 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[UKenglish,german]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\VerbatimFootnotes

\usepackage[shrink=10,babel=true]{microtype}    

\begin{document}

...Bret Victor\footnote{cf. \url{http://worrydream.com/\#!/TheFutureOfProgramming} and \url{http://worrydream.com/\#!/MediaForThinkingTheUnthinkable}; 
also the work of...}.

\end{document}
```

I don't want to disable any of the packages used here. Of course I can change the text, but that's also not the idea...

---

This is with TeX Live 2015.

Comment: Try to load `hyperref` as last package.

Comment: That said, trying your example I only get a warning `name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one` but otherwise it compiles. What are you using? I am on TeXlive 2016 and tried the example with pdflatex.

Comment: @samcarter thanks, putting `hyperref` last fixed the issue indeed. I use Tex Live 2015 (standard for Debian stable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get no error with your example document, but an important warning

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name {Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

which is due to not loading `hyperref` last.

There are also other problems in your preamble, here is a better ordered version:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%% page setup
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={150mm,237mm},
 left=30mm,
 top=30mm,
}

%% general setup
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish,german]{babel}

%% fonts
\usepackage[lf]{venturis} %% lf option gives lining figures as default; 
\usepackage[shrink=10,babel=true]{microtype}    

%% other packages
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

%% hyperref should be last
\usepackage{hyperref}
% get rid of the horrible coloured boxes around links
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}

\VerbatimFootnotes

\begin{document}

...Bret Victor\footnote{cf.\@ \url{http://worrydream.com/\#!/TheFutureOfProgramming} 
and \url{http://worrydream.com/\#!/MediaForThinkingTheUnthinkable}; 
also the work of...}.

\end{document}
```

Note that `pdftex` should not be passed to `hyperref`, nor `colorlinks=false` if you do `colorlinks` in `\hypersetup`.

The period after `cf` is not sentence ending, so it should be followed by `\@`.

I didn't try to solve the underfull line in the footnote.

[image]

Production note: I used `\textwidth=2cm` just for making a smaller picture.

Comment: The error cannot be reproduced if you change margin or text width

Comment: @EmitTaste I tried without `\textwidth=2cm` before producing the smaller picture and got no error whatsoever. I didn't change your settings with `\geometry`. By the way, I tried your example with TeX 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016: no error.

Comment: Anyway, putting `\usepackage{hyperref}` last fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The line in the `.log` file

```
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 39.
```

is *not* an error or warning. It is just an information (maybe helpful in debugging problems).

The file compiles without error with pdflatex. Three issues:

- `hyperref` should be loaded later. For example, it will not see package `babel` with its languages.
- `german` for `babel` means the "Alte Rechtschreibung`. Since the orthography has changed in [German orthography reform of 1996][1], the language name for`babel`is`ngerman`.
- The wrong footnote link is due to an incompatibility of `\VerbatimFootnotes` with `hyperref`. In the example, `\VerbatimFootnotes` is not needed, otherwise, `hyperref`'s footnote linking can be disabled by option `hyperfootnotes=false`.

Comment: verbatim footnotes are needed in other footnotes of that same full text.